# tkinter stipple option misbehaving in OS X

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

I am running this sample [code](http://www.kosbie.net/cmu/fall-11/15-112/handouts/misc-demos/src/semi-transparent-stipple-demo.py) to test `stipple` on both Windows and OS X but the results are different. What is going on?

[Windows](http://imgur.com/ipCtUVr) vs.
[OS X](http://imgur.com/cl21NwQ)

```
# semi-transparent-stipple-demo.py
# note: stipple only works for some objects (like rectangles)
# and not others (like ovals).  But it's better than nothing...

from Tkinter import *

def redrawAll(canvas):
    canvas.delete(ALL)
    # draw a red rectangle on the left half
    canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 250, 600, fill="red")
    # draw semi-transparent rectangles in the middle
    canvas.create_rectangle(200,  75, 300, 125, fill="blue", stipple="")
    canvas.create_rectangle(200, 175, 300, 225, fill="blue", stipple="gray75")
    canvas.create_rectangle(200, 275, 300, 325, fill="blue", stipple="gray50")
    canvas.create_rectangle(200, 375, 300, 425, fill="blue", stipple="gray25")
    canvas.create_rectangle(200, 475, 300, 525, fill="blue", stipple="gray12")

def init(canvas):
    redrawAll(canvas)

########### copy-paste below here ###########

def run():
    # create the root and the canvas
    root = Tk()
    canvas = Canvas(root, width=500, height=600)
    canvas.pack()
    # Store canvas in root and in canvas itself for callbacks
    root.canvas = canvas.canvas = canvas
    # Set up canvas data and call init
    canvas.data = { }
    init(canvas)
    # set up events
    # root.bind("<Button-1>", mousePressed)
    # root.bind("<Key>", keyPressed)
    # timerFired(canvas)
    # and launch the app
    root.mainloop()  # This call BLOCKS (so your program waits until you close the window!)

run()
```

Answer (score 3):

As best as I can tell, stippling has never worked on OSX -- it may have worked under OS9 but as recently as 2011 this issue was discussed and marked "closed, won't fix" in an [OSX Tk stipple ticket discussion](http://rkeene.org/projects/tcl/tk.fossil/tkthistory/2954673fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff) for Tk 8.5

If you look at current sources for Tk 8.6, things continue to look grim:

```
void *
TkMacOSXMakeStippleMap(
    Drawable drawable,      /* Window to apply stipple. */
    Drawable stipple)       /* The stipple pattern. */
{
    return NULL;
}
```

Though I have seen other [Tk sources where this function is defined](http://web.mit.edu/6.863/src/tk8.5.1/macosx/tkMacOSXDraw.c), I can't tell if they correspond to any official release.

It's not just an issue of implementing stippling in OSX, they seem to have an issue with simply documenting that stippling doesn't work in OSX!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. Would you happen to know if it will work in Ubuntu Linux? Also, are there any other Python libraries like Tkinter that has support for image alpha (changing opacity of filled polygons)?

Comment: If I had to guess, the stippling capability is built into X windows and Tk just passes it along under Linux.  So yes.